# Add Element Underneath Flex Items

Tags: css, flexbox

I want the load more button to be on it's own row.

But to work with my project, it needs to remain inside the .mod-c-tab-content-row container.

I'm hoping there is some sort of special line break but not sure this is possible when using flex.

Any helps appreciated.

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/jacksonjack/pen/MWKpxWw

Code here:

```css
.mod-c-tab-content-row {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.mod-c-tab-col {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 33.333333%;
  flex: 1 1 33.333333%;
  max-width: 33.333333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mod-c-tab-content-row">
  <div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <button class="c-btn">Load more</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `position: absolute` to your button, you can move your button outside the flow of it's container without changing your HTML structure:

```css
.mod-c-tab-content-row {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.mod-c-tab-col {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 33.333333%;
  flex: 1 1 33.333333%;
  max-width: 33.333333%;
}

.c-btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, 0 );
}
```

```html
<div class="mod-c-tab-content-row">
  <div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="mod-c-tab-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  </div>
  <button class="c-btn">Load more</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the button in a div tag.

```
<div class="tab-content-action">
  <button class="c-btn">Load more</button>
</div>
```

And style part

```
.tab-content-action{
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```